# Does Cordova support SQLite databases?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

If yes, then how do I use SQLite in Cordova 3.5?

I have already tried WebSQL (which works fine), but I want to use SQLite.

Comment: *Yes*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719549/values-not-inserting-in-sqlite-database-using-cordova/. Please do your research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will support for any version

But need to write native code (android - java, windows - C#, ios - Objective C, ....)