# values not inserting in sqlite database using cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created a form for inserting data from textbox into the database and when I run it in the browser I can see the table is created and values are inserted.

I tried implementing the same using cordova and table getting created and values are not getting inserted..

**Here is my coding**..

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",  function()
{
var db=window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name : "mydb"});
var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,username      TEXT,password TEXT,firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT,hobby  TEXT,email TEXT)";
var insertStatement = " INSERT INTO login(username,password,firstname,lastname,hobby,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,? ) ";
function initDatabase()  // Function Call When Page is ready.

{

try {

    if (!window.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.

    {

       // alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');

    }

    else {

        createTable();  // If supported then call Function for create table in SQLite

    }

 }

 catch (e) {

    if (e == 2) {

        // Version number mismatch. 

        console.log("Invalid database version.");

    } else {

        console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");

    }

    return;

   }

   }


   function createTable() // Function Call When Page is ready.

   {


   var res=db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], onError); });

  alert("Successfully created the table");

   }
  function onError(tx, error) // Function for Hendeling Error...

   {

 // alert(error.message);

  }
  });
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",  function()
  {
  var db=window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name : "mydb"});         

  function insertRecord()
  {
    var usernameold = $('input:text[id=username]').val();

    var passwordold = $('input:password[id=pass]').val();

     var firstnameold = $('input:text[id=firstname]').val();

    var lastnameold = $('input:text[id=lastname]').val();

    var hobbyold = $('input:text[id=hobby]').val();

    var emailold = $('input:text[id=email]').val();

    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(insertStatement,     [usernameold,passwordold,firstnameold, lastnameold,hobbyold,emailold]/*,loadAndReset, onError*/) });

    alert("Successfully created the table");
    }
   });

   $(document).ready(function()
   {
    initDatabase();
   $("#submit").click(insertRecord); 
   });
```

Tried saving and importing the database from **fileexprorer->data->data->projectpackage->databases->mydb.db**

then **firefox->sqlitemanager->connectdb**

I can see the table is getting created and the values are not inserting
Plz help...

Comment: your login table is created or not? and also first try like this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Yes the login table is created

Comment: can you explain your code structure..

Comment: When insert record in database it takes some time between this if we submit our page the record is not inserted. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672814/canvas-signature-touch-creates-issue-in-phonegap

Comment: the above code has 6 textbox fields and once we enter the values in the textbox and click on submit button the values must get inserted in the database...I can see that the table is getting created and the values are not getting inserted..

Comment: the problem is when the form is submitted immediatly, so db not inserts values(usually db takes some time to insert). instaed of submit a form just use one button to store data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can insert the values:

```
    db.transaction(function (tx) 
  { 
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (username,pass,firstname,lastname,hobby,email)VALUES("'+un+'","'+ps+'","'+fs+'","'+ls+'","'+hb+'","'+ed+'")');

  });
  });
  }
```

Where

```
   var un= $("#username").val();

   var ps= $("#pass").val();

   var fs = $('input:text[id=firstname]').val();

   var ls = $('input:text[id=lastname]').val();

   var hb = $('input:text[id=hobby]').val();

   var ed = $('input:text[id=email]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html check the above link for db storage queries.
   Try with the below code . Hope this will help you.

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">     
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    
        var nameval,pwdval,fnameval,lnameval,hobbyval,emailval;

function onDeviceReady() {          
    var db = window.openDatabase("Logindetails_DB", "1.0", "Logindetails_DB", 100000);      
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function validationCheck(){
     nameval=document.getElementById('u_name').value;
     pwdval=document.getElementById('u_pwd').value;
     fnameval=document.getElementById('u_firstname').value;
     lnameval=document.getElementById('u_lastname').value;
     hobbyval=document.getElementById('u_hobby').value;
     emailval=document.getElementById('u_email').value;
            if(document.getElementById('u_name').value==""){
                    alert('Enter Your Name');                       
            }
             if(document.getElementById('u_pwd').value==""){
                alert('Enter Your Password');                   
            }   
            if(document.getElementById('u_firstname').value==""){
                    alert('Enter Your FirstName');                      
            }
            if(document.getElementById('u_lastname').value==""){
                    alert('Enter Your LastName');                       
            }
            if(document.getElementById('u_hobby').value==""){
                    alert('Enter Your HobbyName');                      
            }
            if(document.getElementById('u_email').value==""){
                    alert('Enter Your Email');                      
            }           
             if(nameval!='' && pwdval!='' && fnameval!='' && lnameval!='' && hobbyval!='' && emailval!=''){ 
             alert('Name'+nameval+'Pwd'+pwdval);                    
                    Insertvalue();                      
                 }

}

function Insertvalue(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Logindetails_DB", "1.0", "Logindetails_DB", 100000);
         db.transaction(getregistdata, transaction_error);                        
    }   
        function getregistdata(tx){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO login (username, password, firstname,lastname,hobby,email) VALUES ("'+nameval+'", "'+pwdval+'","'+fnameval+'","'+lnameval+'","'+hobbyval+'","'+emailval+'")');
                        alert('Record Inserted Successfully');
                }

        function transaction_error(tx, error) {
         alert("Database Error: " + error);
        }           


// Populate the database

   function populateDB(tx) {    
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, firstname TEXT NOT NULL,lastname TEXT NOT NULL,hobby TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL)');              

   }
    // Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}  

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");

} 
</script>
 </head>
<body>

   <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
        User Name: <br><input type="text" name="u_name" id="u_name"><br><br>
        Password:<br><input type="text" name="u_pwd" id="u_pwd"><br><br>
        First Name<br> <input type="text" name="u_firstname" id="u_firstname"><br><br>
        Last Name<br> <input type="text" name="u_lastname" id="u_lastname"><br><br>
        Hobby<br> <input type="text" name="u_hobby" id="u_hobby"><br><br>
        Email<br> <input type="text" name="u_email" id="u_email"><br><br>
   <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="button" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="validationCheck()">
   </div>
  </form>

  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: But Im using sqlplugin for this..shouldn't we use this  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase ?

Comment: sorry i didn't tried with sqlite plugin, i have tried based on the phonegap docs. did u called your insertRecord() function in form button onclick. check whether u r getting value on the var usernameold.did u alert your values usernameold and all.

Comment: have alert() the usernameold,passwordold etc and error in getting the values

Comment: any other alternatives?

Comment: did u included this code in your xml config.xml file <feature name="Storage">
         <param name="android-package"    value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60816/discussion-between-nathiya-and-manikandan).

Comment: i am using cordova 2.9.0 version. which cordova version did you using. correctly include your cordova version file name in your header.

Comment: Yes I have included that in the config.xml which is in the res->xml folder and I am using version 3.5.0

Comment: did u have included this permission in mainfest.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and in header <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> instead of cordova.js give me the js file name u having in your assets folder.

Comment: The <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> is already included in the manifest file and its also cordova.js